# Vue.JS - Error in nextTick: “TypeError: Cannot read property ‘badInput’ of undefined”

Tags: vue.js

I received this Error:

```
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Error in nextTick: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'badInput' of undefined"

found in

---> <MdSelect> at src/components/MdField/MdSelect/MdSelect.vue
       <MdField> at src/components/MdField/MdField.vue
         <MdCardContent> at src/components/MdCard/MdCardContent/MdCardContent.vue
           <MdCard> at src/components/MdCard/MdCard.vue
             <MdContent> at src/components/MdContent/MdContent.vue
               <MdDialog> at src/components/MdDialog/MdDialog.vue
                 <Loading> at src/components/Loading.vue
                   <QuadroHorarioSalaNormal>
                     <Loading> at src/components/Loading.vue
                       <MdContent> at src/components/MdContent/MdContent.vue
                         <MdAppContent> at src/components/MdApp/MdAppContent.vue
                           <MdAppSideDrawer> at src/components/MdApp/MdAppSideDrawer.vue
                             <ComSidebarLayout> at src/layouts/ComSideBar.vue
                               <App> at src/App.vue
                                 <Root>
```

This error occurs when an option is selected in the select:

```
<md-dialog :md-active.sync="showInserirDisciplina">
            <md-dialog-title><md-icon>article</md-icon> Incluir Disciplina</md-dialog-title>
            <md-content>
                <form novalidate class="md-layout" style="min-width: 500px;">
                    <md-card class="md-layout-item md-size-100 md-small-size-100">
                        <md-card-content>
                            <md-field>
                                <label for="disciplina"> Disciplina</label>
                                <md-select v-model="disciplina" name="disciplina" id="disciplina" @md-selected="carregaDisciplinasEquivalentes" class="filtro" style="color:#6361FB !important">
                                    <md-option :value="0" ></md-option>
                                    <md-option :value="c.codigoDisciplina" v-for="c in dadosDisciplinas">
                                        {{c.disciplina}}
                                    </md-option>
                                </md-select>
                            </md-field>
```

Please, someone can help me?

Best regards for all reply,

Comment: If you take a look at the stacktrace there must be an entry pointing to the MdSelect component code - click on it and then place a breakpoint in the code. Then reproduce the error - it will trigger the breakpoint and then you will be able to see the callstack and if you select different entry in the callstack you will be able to see the values of variables at that place and point in time. It might be a bug in the component - or in your code (improper usage of the component) but you can not tell until you do some debugging.

Answer (score 4):

As per the [github issue](https://github.com/vuematerial/vue-material/issues/2285) this is a bug in the vue material codebase - and looks like someone has provided a PR so ***you may*** be able to fix by upgrading the version.

**Personally I fixed this quickly** by following the advice of user "bart-src" there and simply changed my local code:

1. Locate node_modules\vue-material\dist\vue-material.js
2. Search for isInvalidValue
3. swap out the code:

**old:**

```
return this.$el.validity.badInput;
```

**new:**

```
return this.$el.validity ? this.$el.validity.badInput : false;
```

*for me this was ~line 1059*

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
npm i vue-material@1.0.0-beta-11
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).